# Popup with gridview get onclick event

Tags: android, popup, android-gridview, onclicklistener

I am showing a popup with grid view of images and I am trying to do some work when user clicks on any of image of grid view. However, I can't get the onClick event of gridview.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getView()` method for rendering the images, call `setOnClickListener` for each `ImageView` and it should work.